# How to insert results from one database to another in c# application

Tags: c#, sql

How can you connect the result of a query from one database and insert it into another in a c# application?

This is what I have so far but it doesnt work.

```
// select from first database
string sCMD_All = "SELECT * FROM table";
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

using (SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sCMD_All, myConn))
    {
        myConn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        da.Fill(ds);
        myConn.Close();
    }
}
DataTable sqTable = ds.Tables[0];

//insert into 2nd database
DataTable newTable = new DataTable();
newTable = sqTable;
using (SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString_M))
{
    string sCMD_I = "INSERT INTO tableNew @newTable";

    using (SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sCMD_I, myConn))
    {
        myConn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
        myConn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: In what way does it not work?  Are you getting errors?

Comment: Your creating a `SqlCommand` without adding the appropriate parameter `@newTable`, you're using `ExecuteReader` for an insert-command instead of `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: do you need myConn.Open() and myConn.Close() once you use using(){} ???

Comment: See [Bulk Insert into SQL from C# App](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nikhilsi/archive/2008/06/11/bulk-insert-into-sql-from-c-app.aspx) blog entry in Nikhil Singhal's Blog.

Answer (score 0):

```
var commandText = 
    @"insert into [server].[database2].[schema].[table] (col1, col2, ...)
    select col1, col2, ... from [server].[database1].[schema].[table]";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: If databases are located on different servers, you should link servers:

`exec sp_addlinkedserver @server = 'server2'`

Comment: This works if the server is the same - and if I make it different and copy it to SQL server management studio the query runs fine - but not in my c# application...

Comment: @"insert into [server1].[database2].[schema].[table] (col1, col2, ...)
    select col1, col2, ... from [server2].[database1].[schema].[table]"

Comment: ...FYI This solution will not work for AZURE based SQL. No sp_linkedservers available in Azure SQL at this time.